# Random Turtle movement, bounce off wall

Tags: python, python-3.x, turtle-graphics

Created the program to randomize the movement of the turtle but cannot get it to bounce off the window/canvas limits. Tried a few solutions posted with similar questions but still no luck.

```
from turtle import Turtle, Screen
import random

def createTurtle(color, width):
    tempName = Turtle("arrow")
    tempName.speed("fastest")
    tempName.color(color)
    tempName.width(width)
    return tempName

def inScreen(screen, turt):

    x = screen.window_height() / 2
    y = screen.window_height() / 2

    min_x, max_x = -x, x
    min_y, max_y = -y, y

    turtleX, turtleY = turt.pos()

    while (min_x <= turtleX <= max_x) and (min_y <= turtleY <= max_y):
        turt.left(random.randrange(360))
        turt.fd(random.randrange(50))
        turtleX, turtleY = turt.pos()
        print(turtleX, ",", turtleY)


wn = Screen()

alpha = createTurtle("red", 3)

inScreen(wn, alpha)

wn.exitonclick()
```

Comment: What is expected and what do you get? Why do you think this is broken?

Comment: @AndreiCioara With the current code, the turtle will move randomly until it hits a wall. After that the loop stops and when I click the window it closes. I'm trying so that when it hits a wall it bounces in a random direction and continues on until forcibly closed.

Comment: It looks like you are exiting the loop when your turtle goes outside of the bounds. Maybe you should stay in your loop forever and have an if statement that modifies the location and direction when you would go out of bounds?

Comment: @BobbyDurrett something like this? 
`    while True:
        turt.left(random.randrange(360))
        turt.fd(random.randrange(50))
        turtleX, turtleY = turt.pos()
        print(turtleX, ",", turtleY)
        if (min_x >= turtleX >= max_x) and (min_y >= turtleY >= max_y):
            turt.setheading(90)
            turtleX, turtleY = turt.pos()`

Comment: I'm voting to close as off-topic because there is no question here (and the implied “What code do I write?” is too broad).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like

```
old_position = turtle.position()  # Assume we're good here.
turtle.move_somehow()  # Turtle computes its new position.
turtle_x, turtle_y = turtle.position()  # Maybe we're off the canvas now.
if not (min_x <= turtle_x <= max_x) or not (min_y <= turtle_y <= max_y):
   turtle.goto(*old_position)  # Back to safely.
   turtle.setheading(180 - turtle.heading())  # Reflect.
```

Comment: Alright, that works! But is there a way to maybe stop or break the current course midway and reflect back? Because currently, let's say the turtle is at an edge, it goes 100units off screen then it returns. Maybe a way to stop or cut it off before the full 100units?

Comment: Either you delegate the next movement to the turtle, or you don't. If you delegate, you should detect the turtle being off limits, and fix it. If you don't, you should compute the new coordinates yourself, independently, and correctly, and split the would-be move into more than one segment (maybe 3 if close to a corner of a rectangle; recursion helps), then commandeer the turtle along the lines of the reflection you computed.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this:

```
while true:
    if (min_x <= turtleX <= max_x) and (min_y <= turtleY <= max_y):
        turt.left(random.randrange(360))
        turt.fd(random.randrange(50))
        turtleX, turtleY = turt.pos()
        print(turtleX, ",", turtleY)
    else:
# Put code here to move the turtle to where it intersected the edge
# and then bounce off
```

I guess you have to figure out where the intersection point is.